How to get internal Spring Boot framework metrics and enhanced observability with OpenTelemetry?
I've been exploring the OpenTelemetry documentation and see that there are two primary methods for enabling OpenTelemetry in Java applications: using the Java Agent Bytecode approach or integrating with Spring Boot Native.
Apart from the benefits mentioned for Spring Boot integration, are there additional advantages? Specifically, I was expecting to see built-in spans and metrics for various Spring Boot modules such as Kafka, Redis, and Spring Data.
Is there a way to capture internal metrics from the Spring Boot framework itself using OpenTelemetry?

What is the benefit of using 'Spring boot open telemetry' libraries vs simple Java instrumentation ?
